# install dependencies for emacs package in a CI environment

Tags: package, testing

I am testing an Emacs package on Travis CI with `ert`. A [PR](https://github.com/tpapp/julia-repl/pull/76) now requires [the s package](https://github.com/magnars/s.el). This is how I currently make sure it's available in the test environment:

```
script:
  - $EMACS --version
  - $EMACS --batch --eval "(progn (package-initialize) (add-to-list 'package-archives (cons \"melpa\" \"https://melpa.org/packages/\") t) (package-refresh-contents) (package-install 's))"
  - $EMACS --batch -L . --eval "(progn (package-initialize) (setq byte-compile-error-on-warn t))" -f batch-byte-compile julia-repl.el
  - $EMACS --batch -L . -l ert --eval "(package-initialize)" -l julia-repl-tests.el -f ert-run-tests-batch-and-exit;
```

which is rather inelegant: I have to eval `(package-initialize)` every time, and manually install `s`. I have the

```
;; Package-Requires: ((emacs "25")(s "1.12"))
```

in the package header, is it possible to somehow grab and install all dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question:

1. Since `--batch` disables init files for Emacs, one has to keep the `(package-initialize)`; best I could do is move it to a file and load it with `-l`.
2. But dependencies do not have to be enumerated manually, `package-install-file` can take care of finding them all.

Details in the PR above.